# Trying to recursively hash values in object

Tags: javascript, recursion, hash

friends. I'm trying to write code that hashes all values in a JSON file, regardless of file structure, while preserving the keys and structure. I'm new to javascript, and am having some trouble. My code hashes the values of big and baz, but doesn't recursively hash the values of cat and bar like I want it to. Ideally, I want the numbers hashed and the names (big, foo, etc.) left alone. Thank you so much! See my code below:

```
var meow = {
  big: 20,
  baz: {
    foo: {
      cat: 3,
      bar: 5

    }
  }
};

console.log(typeof(meow.baz.foo));

function hashobj(obj)
{
    var valarray = Object.keys(obj);
    var zer = valarray[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < valarray.length; i++)
    {
        var vaz = valarray[i];
        if(typeof(obj[vaz] != "object"))
        {
            obj[vaz] = sha256(obj[vaz] + buf);
        }
        if(typeof(obj[vaz]) == "object")
        {
            console.log("HERE");
            hashobj(obj[vaz]);
        }
    }
}
hashobj(meow);
console.log(meow);
```

Comment: 20 is never printed because `hashobj` is never called according to your code snippet. Also, why do you expect 20 to be printed? Have you verified that the first key is actually `big` and not `baz`?

Comment: `zer` is variable and not a property, so `obj.zer` evaluates to `undefined`. To access property dynamically use: `obj[zer]`

Comment: Oh my bad, I do call it, and it prints "undefined"

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Object keys don't necessarily retain their order, either, so you may want to check want valarray[0] returns, if you expecting `zer` to equal `big.`

Comment: Ohh good to know. Now I'm trying to figure out why the recursion isn't working. I so appreciate you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to do this recursively, I would suggest using a generic transformation function that handles the recursive object structure and delegates to a supplied function the actual work of transforming the leaf nodes.

In this version, the `transform` function does all the heavy lifting.  It calls the supplied function on scalar values and recursively calls itself on objects and arrays, recreating the structure of the original with the new values.  This is quite reusable.

We create our `hashObject` function by passing `transform` a function which does the sha256 encoding of our values.

```js
const transform = (fn) => (obj) =>
  Array.isArray (obj)
    ? obj .map (transform (fn))
  : Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) 
        .map (([k, v]) => [k, transform (fn) (v)])
      )
  : fn (obj)

const hashObj = transform ((n) => sha256 (String (n)))

const meow = {big: 20, baz: {foo: {cat: 3, bar: 5, qux: [1, 2, 3]}}};
               // added to demonstrate arrays --------^

console .log (hashObj (meow))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/js-sha256@0.9.0/src/sha256.js"></script>
```

Comment: This isn't a well-formed tree data structure where children are hold by a unqiue property, but the shape arise from abritrarily nested objects and arrays. I think I will implement a general enough, recursive left and right fold for such tree-like structures to be able to traverse it in pre- and post-order respecively. having such general folds would allow us to abstract the recurison anf focus on the task at hand.

Comment: @scriptum: that would be quite useful. The above is not meant for traversals, although similar techniques could be used for that. (Some of the work from user Thankyou probably offers suggestions in that direction.) If  you're thinking that such pre-/post-order traversals could then be used to solve this sort of transformation problem, I'd be curious to see how.

Comment: I dunno yet but the value passed to the reducing function is probably the whole object at your current position, so that you can add new or delete existing props. On the other hand there are probably not that many operations that are performed at all leafs/data notes uniformly as in your example. So it's probably a silly idea and lenses/prisms are a better choice..

Comment: @scriptum: I think there may be a lot of merit in it.  I'd be curious to see it work.  I've used variants of the above that pass both the key and the value to the transforming function; that makes sense. I'd be curious to see if something passing the equivalent output object for the node would be useful.

Comment: Ohhh a very elegant solution. I hope to one day write code like this. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 2):

Scott's answer is wonderful. The [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), `?.`, is supported most places now and is particularly useful for runtime type checking. I'm sharing this post as a way to see `transform` expressed using this modern feature -

```js
function transform (f, o)
{ switch (o?.constructor) // <- any o, even null and undefined
  { case Array:
      return o.map(_ => transform(f, _))
    case Object:
      return Object.fromEntries
        ( Object
            .entries(o)
            .map(([k, _]) => [k, transform(f, _)])
        )
    default:
      return f(o)
  }
}

const result =
  transform
    ( _ => sha256(String(_))
    , {big: 20, baz: {foo: {cat: 3, bar: 5, qux: [1, 2, 3]}}}
    )
    
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/js-sha256@0.9.0/src/sha256.js"></script>
```

```json
{
  "big": "f5ca38f748a1d6eaf726b8a42fb575c3c71f1864a8143301782de13da2d9202b",
  "baz": {
    "foo": {
      "cat": "4e07408562bedb8b60ce05c1decfe3ad16b72230967de01f640b7e4729b49fce",
      "bar": "ef2d127de37b942baad06145e54b0c619a1f22327b2ebbcfbec78f5564afe39d",
      "qux": [
        "6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b",
        "d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35",
        "4e07408562bedb8b60ce05c1decfe3ad16b72230967de01f640b7e4729b49fce"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

One distinct advantage to this approach is the `Array` and `Object` branches can appear in any order. When using `Array.isArray(t)` it must be checked *before* checking `Object(t) === t`. It's a subtle thing but is worth noting -

```js
// also correct!

function transform (f, o)
{ switch (o?.constructor)
  { case Object:                   // <- type-check Object
      return // ...
    case Array:                    // <- type-check Array
      return // ...
    default:
      return f(o)
  }
}
```

---

You may also wish to hash an entire object. Here's one possibility to implement a generic `hash` using a generic `traverse` function -

```js
function* traverse (t, r = [])
{ switch (t?.constructor)  // <- any t, even null and undefined
  { case Array:
    case Set:
    case Map:
      for (const [k, _] of t.entries())
        yield* traverse(_, [...r, k])
      break
    case Object:
      for (const [k, _] of Object.entries(t))
        yield* traverse(_, [...r, k])
      break
    default:
      yield [r, t]
  }
}

function hash (t)
{ const r = sha256.create()
  for (const [k, v] of traverse(t))
    r.update(k.concat(v).join(":"))
  return r.hex()
}


const input =
  {big: 20, baz: {foo: {cat: 3, bar: 5, qux: [1, 2, 3]}}}

console.log(hash("foo"), hash("foo"))
console.log(hash([1,2,3]), hash([1,2,3]))
console.log(hash(input), hash(input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/js-sha256@0.9.0/src/sha256.js"></script>
```

```
2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae
2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae

492f06976c8bc705819f5d33d71be6a80a547b03f87c377e3543605d8260159c
492f06976c8bc705819f5d33d71be6a80a547b03f87c377e3543605d8260159c

d1ae8b8641d3d6d65b1e4eecab0484a9f9618f2aabafe473c8bb0b4f6382695c
d1ae8b8641d3d6d65b1e4eecab0484a9f9618f2aabafe473c8bb0b4f6382695c
```

Comment: Great as always.  I'm mixed about the technique.  While I really like `?.`, I prefer working with expressions rather than statements like `switch`.  I also have a question about your use of `_`.  I usually use that for positional parameters I want to ignore.  But here you use it as just another variable.  Any particular reason for, say, `.map(([k, _]) => [k, transform(f, _)])` instead of `.map(([k, v]) => [k, transform(f, v)])`?

Comment: Oh, and using that `traverse` is so much nicer than my first attempt.  I really need to consider generator functions more often.

Comment: I much prefer expressions as well but I'm exploring `switch (t?.constructor)` because it gives us O(1) access to the matching `case` and a more consistent way to type-check using simple `case MyType: ...` and `case MyOtherType: ...` blocks. But yes it is ugly!!

Comment: Another thing I'm exploring is `_` for partial application. It's just an easy way for my mind to say "do something with this thing, `_`, whatever it is. I don't care to name it because it's not my place to know it." I find it helps my brain focus on the critical parts, `r` and `k` in this case, and free your mind from one extra variable that just gets passed through. Thanks for giving me the chance to explain it! :D

Comment: I might prefer `({array: fn1, object: fn2} [t?.constructor] || defaultFn) (t)`.  But for multiple collapsed cases such as Array, Set, Map above, this would require externally defined `fn`s in order to avoid redundancy.  That might not be as nice.

Comment: Wow! I appreciate the time you took to explain and demo the code. And thank you for the function that hashes an entire object. Might be useful down the line :)

Answer (score 1):

Everything is ok but the parenthesis:

```
    if(typeof(obj[vaz] != "object"))
```

should read:

```
    if(typeof(obj[vaz]) != "object")
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much! Please forgive the rookie mistake :) Different language, same old mistakes.